# Change Unit ID in modbus_read_registers of libmodbus

Tags: modbus-tcp, libmodbus

I have used the libmodbus to build a project to connect to my device by modbus-tcp. The project run. But Unit ID is wrong. My ID slave is 0xFE. However it is fixed as 0xFF whenever I send a modbus-tcp package. I had tried to change it by function `modbus_set_slave` but it did not work.
How can I change it?

Libmodbus: https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus

```
"modbus_read_registers(modbus_t *ctx, int addr, int nb, uint16_t *dest);"
```

It's clear that I cannot put Unit ID in above function to read value a register.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTaiQ.png)

Comment: Have you tried [`modbus_set_slave`](https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus/blob/master/doc/modbus_set_slave.txt) - The docs are a little confusing but the library [appears to use that](https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus/blob/master/src/modbus-tcp.c#L116) as the Unit Identifier.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Although I set 'req[6] = 254;', I does not work

Comment: So you edited the library? (probably easier if you include a full example). It does appear that the [max slaveID is 247](https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus/blob/master/src/modbus-tcp.c#L80) (with `0xFF` also allowed). This is technically correct for Modbus RTU (section 2.2 in the spec - 248-255 are reserved) but I can't see anything in the Modbus TCP spec on this. [This issue](https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus/issues/153) is somewhat relevant.

Comment: I have to edit the library because my device have ID = 254. I have no choice. I noticed the max slaveID, and I detected also that  modbus_set_slave in the example  is only used for Modbus RTU. Do you have any ideas that is useful in my case?

Comment: If you have created your own version of the library then you should be able to send whatever unit ID you want to (alternatively there are alternative libraries). Have you verified that the device does respond when you send it a request with the right unit ID?

Comment: I observe on wireshark  some modbus packages, which are exchange between my device and a tool. There is no doubt: the ID=254

Comment: OK - It looks like your options are modify the library, use a different library, or submit an issue and wait for the libmodbus devs to change this (if they agree to do so). If you have modified the library and it's still not working you will need to provide details of your changes (based upon a quick look I think it should only take one change [here](https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus/blob/master/src/modbus-tcp.c#L80)).

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I will let you know once the result is out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually function `modbus_set_slave` is the answer. The reason why it did not work is that I made a mistake with the link. Moreover, I can chang the ID unit by fixing it in other function because  the library is available to modify.